# How to make a for loop in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

How is it possible to make a for loop for this command: bcdboot c:\windows
So basiclly I want a loop that does something like this: IF bcdboot is not in C then try bcdboot a:\windows if its not there then b,c,d,e,f,g etc etc until it finds it then run bcdboot (depending on where it is) :\windows command. Sorry if i'm unclear my English is not the best.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for %i in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do @(if exist %i:\windows bcdboot %i\windows)
```

Comment: I'll try it, thanks for taking your time and helping

Comment: This is a very inefficient answer. Use `wmic logicaldisk get caption` to get a list of actual drives ...